# How to clean up a Linux installation?

Tags: ubuntu, apt, package-management

I've been using Linux (mainly Ubuntu) for about two years now. I've had several installations on several machines. Something that inevitably happens on any OS installation is that I install something I need that day, maybe a library or CLI utility, use it for a week, and then forget about it.

I'm sure I've got several GB of unused packages taking up space on my installations. How can I clean up my installation to make sure that I only have things that I want?

I'm aware of `apt-get autoremove` to remove unused dependencies.

I'm aware of `apt list --installed` to view all packages installed through `apt`.

I'm aware of `dpkg -L` to view all files installed from a package.

Suppose I were to look though the output of `apt list --installed` and remove things I don't want by either `apt-get purge` or deleting every file from `dpkg -L <package>`. Eventually, I would have cleaned up everything installed through my package manager, right?

Where else should I look? Not everything on my computer was installed through `apt`. For example, .deb packages like google-chrome and things installed via scripts. Where would these things live? And what's the best way to find them?

My goal is to shrink my installation down to basically a fresh install plus the things I use all the time.

Thanks, all!

Comment: .deb packages (like google-chrome) are listed since they utilize the package management to be installed.

Comment: A good method to get rid of old program packages, that you no longer use is to make a fresh installation, and then add the [extra] packages that you need, when you need them. I think it can be at least as fast and smooth as uninstalling things that you can hardly remember. Please remember that installing a Linux distro is very fast. - You might keep the home directory for the settings and of course your personal files. I keep the personal files in a 'data' partition, so it is independent of the operating system. It is a good time now right after the release of Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.

Comment: You just need to search for manually installed packages and then purge them.

Answer (score 0):

One method for keeping your machine clean is to install everything you want to test or for a specific purpose inside a docker container (this is what I actually do).

Another method is to test the snap/flatpak/appimage packages. These are bundles with all the libraries they use already included, easy to install, easy to remove and conflict avoidance.